# Exclude <li> with specific text in <a> tag of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to exclude `<li>` with specific text in the `<a>` tag

HTML:-

```
<ul>
<li class ="Group Select">
  <span><a>Good</a></span>
</li>
<li class ="Group NotSelect">
  <span><a>Bad</a></span>
</li>
<li class ="Group NotSelect">
   <span><a>What</a></span>
</li>
<li class ="Group NotSelect Hidden">
  <span><a>Better</a></span>
</li>
<li class ="Group NotSelect">
  <span><a>Best</a></span>
</li>
<li>
  <span><a>BadDuplicate</a></span>
</li>
```

In The end, I want li with class Group Select or Group NotSelect but not Group NotSelect Hidden and I do not want li which has "What" in its `<a>` tag

So far

```
$possibleli = $('li.Group').not("[class='Group NotSelect Hidden']");
```

This gives me all `li's` that I need but I want to remove li that has what in its `<a>` tag

Comment: so further filter `$possibleli` to eliminate that span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/%20':contains') selector combined with the .not function (or the not selector combined with the :contains selector) like this:

```
$possibleli = $('li.Group').not("[class='Group NotSelect Hidden']").not(':contains(What)');
```

or

```
$possibleli = $('li.Group:not(.Hidden):not(:contains(What))');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".Group.Select, .Group.NotSelect").not(".Hidden, :contains('What')").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

I want li with class Group Select or Group NotSelect <br>
but not Group NotSelect Hidden <br>and I do not want li which has "What" in its A tag

<ul>
  <li class ="Group Select">
    <span><a>Group Select</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class ="Group NotSelect">
    <span><a>Group NotSelect</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class ="Group NotSelect">
    <span><a>What</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class ="Group NotSelect Hidden">
    <span><a>Group NotSelect Hidden</a></span>
  </li>
  <li class ="Group NotSelect">
    <span><a>Group NotSelect</a></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span><a>BadDuplicate</a></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```